# Is _method=DELETE really supported?

Tags: api, instagram

I just noticed that my application can not remove a like on a media object.  My code for liking / unliking is identical except I add the parameter _method=DELETE to the unlike case (both use POST).  The documentation states that this is supported, and it's pretty common for RESTful API given the lack of support in most browsers for DELETE.  I've tried in from the Apigee console too, and the same problem seems to exist, however DELETE does seen to work.  I'd attach screenshot from the Apigee console, but apparently I need more points or something.

Comment: Link to screenshot of Apigee Console: https://plus.google.com/104005479611862647489/posts/gUobUtupB5k And one more case: https://plus.google.com/104005479611862647489/posts/WMaQFdVao8X

Comment: Are you including the parameters as get parameters or post parameters?

Comment: I've tried it both ways.  For adding a like, it seems to want all parameters on the URL (GET style) even though it's a POST.  I should also clarify one point: the two screen shots I attached look like both are working.  It's only by checking outside the API I determined that the _method=DELETE one didn't actually do anything.

Comment: Have you tried with a likes / comments on a few different objects? There have been known problems in the past with likes / comments from the API not registering or taking a long time to register. Maybe it is the same thing for unlike / comment deletion.

Comment: I found a way to get the platform I was using to send a real DELETE, which seems to work perfectly and consistently, so I stopped worrying about it. Someone from Instagram did contact me about the bug, but no final resolution yet.

Comment: Andy - Thanks for reporting this through the Bug Tool. Fix is on the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is really supported, but it has been broken since February 3rd. It has now been fixed!